# Get multiple values in self.fields

Tags: python, django

```
fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'birth_date']
user__first_name, user__last_name, birth_date = self.fields.get(fields)
```

As `self.fields` is a dictionnary, it is not possible to do such thing. How could it possible to modify it so that it works?

```
    198     def check_user__first_name_user__last_name_birth_date(self):
    199         import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
    200 
--> 201         fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'birth_date']
    202         user__first_name, user__last_name, birth_date = self.fields.get(fields)
    203         for m in self._check(CustomerProfile, user__first_name=user__first_name,
    204                              user__last_name=user__last_name,
    205                              birth_date=birth_date):
    206             self._match(m.user, _('Same first name, last name and birth date.'),
    207                         fields, ', '.join(map(str, self.fields.get(fields))))
```

Comment: Can you show more code so that we can understand what you're trying to do?

Comment: If `self.fields` has always the same number of elements, always ordered in the same way, you can do `user__first_name, user__last_name, birth_date = self.fields`

Comment: I modified my code @user6731765

Comment: Sorry, self.fields is a dictionary instead of a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `self.fields` is a dictionary, you need something that's the equivalent of:

```
user__first_name, user__last_name, birth_date = (self.fields.get("first_name"),
                                                 self.fields.get("last_name"),
                                                 self.fields.get("birth_date"))
```

So, for example, using a list comprehension:

```
fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'birth_date']
user__first_name, user__last_name, birth_date = [self.fields.get(x) for x in fields]
```

Answer (score 0):

In python list objects do not have get.
The proper way to do this would be...

```
>>> user__first_name, user__last_name, birth_date = fields
```